# Need to Count results of a list created in PHP

Tags: php, list, count

Okay I have a list being populated and echoed out on a page.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `game_toe` WHERE `owner`='$mech_units'";
$mydata = mysql_query($sql);

while($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){

echo "<td>" . $record['units'] . "</td>";
```

Now the results fluctuate depending on the number of 'mech_units' there are. What I need is to display how many are being displayed in the list. Any suggestions?

Comment: take `count($mydata)`. count($arr) will give you the count of lists you are getting from db.

Comment: @Niranjan - `count($record)` will list the number of columns; not the number of rows: [mysql_num_rows()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) does that

Comment: @Niranjan: uh, no... you can't count a db result handle. it's not an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest using mysqli.

You could declare a variable which increases by one every time you echo a 'mech_unit'.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `game_toe` WHERE `owner`='$mech_units'";
$mydata = mysql_query($sql);

$i = 0;

while($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){

    $i++;

    echo "<td>" . $record['units'] . "</td>";

}

echo "There are " . $i . " mech_units.";
```

Another option would be to use the `mysql_num_rows()` function.

Comment: Thanks guys. Super helpful!

Answer (score 4):

you can use built in function `mysql_num_rows($mydata)`. This will give you the total number of records that are fetched.